# How to execute bash script on an Azure Linux VM from Azure Functions app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-vm, azure-linux

I need to call a bash script on an Azure Linux VM from an azure function app, and I need it to use the compute on that VM and not my resource plan for my function app.

I know I can perform remote execution via Azure CLI, but I can't seem to wrap my mind around calling it from an interval triggered Function App.

thanks in advance

Comment: Since you want to run a script on Azure Linux VM, why do you not use Custom Script Extension: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux

Comment: @JimXu Can CSE be called from an azure function app?

Comment: Please refer to the sample : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-dotnet-manage-virtual-machine-using-vm-extensions/blob/b5f7a637a089b8a7cfdbe9abe2a46e4eef9f7caa/Program.cs#L167